# C# inherit(kind off)/use the properties of multiple classes in a single class

Tags: c#

Let's say I have 2 classes like this:

```
public class A
{
    public string P1{ get; set; }
    public string P2{ get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string P3{ get; set; }
    public string P4{ get; set; }
}
```

and I need a class like this:

```
public class C
{
    public string P1{ get; set; }
    public string P2{ get; set; }
    public string P3{ get; set; }
    public string P4{ get; set; }
}
```

it it possible for the class C to use class A and B instead of re-declaring all the properties ?
(I need this for DTOs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't**, as multiple inheritance is only for interfaces in C#.

## Hacks

I:

```
public class C : { public A; public B; }
```

II:

```
public interface IA { string P1, P2; }    
public interface IB { string P3, P4; }

public class C : IA, IB { string P1, P2, P3, P4; }
```

III:

```
public class A { public string P1, P2; }
public class B : A { public string P3, P4; }

public class C : B {}
```

As for the DTO, maybe these links [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998527.aspx); [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978717.aspx) could be useful:

If not, you could build your class dynamically using reflection.

[Build **dynamically**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx) a new `C` class containing all the public properties of both `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 7):

No, multiple inheritance is not supported in C#. It can either use A or B, not both.

This is doable, but maybe not pretty:

```cs
public class C
{
   public A APart { get; set; }

   public B BPart { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define interfaces IA and IB which A and B both implement and both of which C implements. The fields still need to be declared in C but they are checked at compile time to ensure parity with A and B.

```
interface IA {
  string P1;
  string P2;
}

interface IB {
  string P3;
  string P4;
}

class A : IA {
  string P1 { get; set; }
  string P2 { get; set; }
}

class B : IB {
  string P3 { get; set; }
  string P4 { get; set; }
}

class C : IA, IB {
  string P1 { get; set; }
  string P2 { get; set; }
  string P3 { get; set; } 
  string P4 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I need this to optimize the construction of DTOs so that for some DTOs that have some common properties to not need to re-declare them in all the other DTOs, so this is not really what I need

Comment: interface cannot contain fields

Answer (score 2):

How about you combine the answers above:

```
interface IA { 
  string P1; 
  string P2; 
} 

interface IB { 
  string P3; 
  string P4; 
} 

class A : IA { 
  string P1 { get; set; } 
  string P2 { get; set; } 
} 

class B : IB { 
  string P3 { get; set; } 
  string P4 { get; set; } 
} 

class C : IA, IB { 
  private IA a;
  private IB b;
  string P1 { get { return a.P1; } set { a.P1 = value } } 
  string P2 { get { return a.P2; } set { a.P2 = value } } 
  string P3 { get { return b.P3; } set { b.P3 = value } } 
  string P4 { get { return b.P4; } set { b.P4 = value } }
}
```

Not super pretty or easy to generate, but it should retain data ownership and class relations.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you make `B` inherit from `A` and then let `C` inherit from `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the solution is to use interfaces. Unline multiple inherritance it doesn't give you automagicness of implementation but it does provide polymorphism and compile time type safety.